# thread safety for NSManagedObject instances?

Tags: cocoa, thread-safety, nsmanagedobject

I have one global instance for one of NSManagedObject type. For the global instance, it has few member variables who are @dynamic properties declared in the following way

```
@property (retain) NSString *value;
```

And I have a few threads that would do the following simple operations

```
myInstance.value = [NSString stringWithString:newValue];
```

So the question is - do I need to synchronize the operation above? or is it naturally thread-safe already (as they are taking care by NSManagedObject)?

Comment: sorry, I fixed it - should be operation above. the operation meant to be the assignment operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, this is not thread-safe. There's a whole article about threading and Core Data which you can read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). Essentially, it says that to properly use threading with Core Data, you need a separate managed object context for each thread. In the "If You Don’t Use Thread Containment" section, it specifically notes that both reading and mutating managed objects across threads can have unwanted effects.